# How to unit test an angular @Output

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

The problem from the coverage report:
[image]

I have this code inside the components.ts

```
export class TimelinePlotComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

form: FormGroup;
@Output() onchange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

constructor() {}

initForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      timeRange: new FormControl(this.time_range_options_active, []),
      metric: new FormControl(this.metric_options_active, []),
      groupBy: new FormControl(this.group_by_options_active, []),
    });

    // How to unit test this part of the code
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe( res => {
      console.log('form-changed');
      this.onchange.emit(res);
    });
  }

}
```

### component.spec.ts

```
  fit('should listen for form changes', async() => {
    component.form.controls['groupBy'].setValue('color');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      // your expectations.
      expect(component.form.valid).toBeTruthy();
      component.onchange.subscribe( res => {
        console.log('res: ', res);
      });

    });
  });
```

> error: nothing is happening, I dont know how to unit test a form that triggers an output event emitter.

As you can see this does not work, any help on how to unit test form changes?

Comment: I think you need to trigger change detection: add `fixture.detectChanges()` before expectation.

Comment: I have tried @HodossySzabolcs :(

Comment: Then I would suggest to create a local variable and subscribe to the output, where you can set the variable to `res`, and test that. I do something similar [here](https://github.com/hodossy/darts-scorer/blob/master/src/app/darts-table/darts-table.component.spec.ts#L28). If that is not sufficient, you can try with a `TestHostComponent` like described [here](https://medium.com/@AikoPath/testing-angular-components-with-input-3bd6c07cfaf6)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't think you need the `whenStable` at all, also the `async` is not necessary. You should use `detectChanges()` to trigger the change detection. But this should only be done before the actual start, to trigger the `ngOnInit` hook (and friends).

Also use a `spy` to make sure the Output has been called:

```
fit('should listen for form changes', () => {
   spyOn(component.onchange, 'emit');
   fixture.detectChanges();

   component.form.controls['groupBy'].setValue('color');

   expect(component.form.valid).toBeTruthy();
   expect(component.onchange.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```